# How to reset Skype web?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, skype

When I use skype web in chrome or firefox, I get empty screen and icon bottom right my profile image keeps rotating i.e. gets stuck in refresh loop.

However, when I start private browsing window and logs into web skype, this does not happen. Skype works normally.

Anyone knows how to reset web skype?

Comment: Have you tried deleting temp files and cookies etc?

Comment: Cookies yes. What temp files? It's web skype app, not desktop.

Comment: Firefox temp files located in your Firefox/Chrome user's profile directory.  Use the UI within Firefox/Chrome to clear the information.

Comment: Browser temp files. Like cached web content etc ...